# how to handle events from a jquery script?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a request a my website for each check/uncheck of these checkboxes.
But, the problem here is that the events that I have included into my webpage doesn't work; when I check/uncheck nothing happens.

Here is my HTML Code :

```
<form method="get" style="display:inline;" class="ListeAlertes"><input type="checkbox" name="fixee" value="true" style="margin-left:40px;margin-right:3px;" @ViewBag.Fixee /> Alertes fixées<input type="checkbox" name="nonFixee" value="true" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:3px;" @ViewBag.NonFixee /> Alertes non-fixées</form>
```

jQuery code :

```
$(".ListeAlertes input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
    var form = $(".ListeAlertes").serialize();
    if (($("input[name='fixee']:checked") && $("input[name='nonFixee']:checked")) || ($("input[name='fixee']:unchecked") && $("input[name='nonFixee']:unchecked"))) {
        $.get("~/Alertes/Index?fixee=true&nonFixee=true");
    }
    if ($("input[name='fixee']:checked") && $("input[name='nonFixee']:unchecked")) {
        $.get("~/Alertes/Index?fixee=true&nonFixee=false");
    }
    if ($("input[name='fixee']:unchecked") && $("input[name='nonFixee']:checked")) {
        $.get("~/Alertes/Index?fixee=false&nonFixee=true");
    }
});
```

Any brilliant idea, please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#chkBoxId').click(function () { }
```

You can use click() function.

'chkBoxId' specified here is the id of the checkbox.

Comment: I need to check if the two checkboxes are also checked or unchecked. Can you just update what I have written to better understand what are you trying to do here ?

Comment: In the fiddle you have given: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eKa8S)  Correct the spelling of alert. Now the alerts will come. Next, you can't directly check for "uncheck". .attr() false for 'checked' can be checked. Make these changes and your code will be fine.

Comment: I've tried to make it better coded and I've got this : http://jsfiddle.net/eKa8S/4/ the alert boxes haven't appeared.

Comment: Its not working because "unchecked" is invalid. There is no such attribute.

Comment: then, when `else` condition haven't been activated ?

Comment: the code is breaking at the "unchecked" specified. That's why its not reaching the else block.

Answer (score 0):

try click event on $('checekbox')  , 
also make sure jquery cdn or its file is included in ur code

Comment: I need to check if the two checkboxes are also checked or unchecked. Can you just update what I have written to better understand what are you trying to do here ?

Comment: you can use $( "input:checked" ).length  to get total no. of checked element or else u can use :checked to check them individually.

Comment: Isn't what I have written as a jquery script ? But, the question here is how to make the posted scripts work together ?

Comment: look http://jsfiddle.net/eKa8S/ I need to catch here the checked/unchecked checkboxes event to display an alert message. But, this doesn't respond to any event made.